# How to load 3rd party jquery library in webpack in test environment with karma. $.fn.something is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, karma-jasmine

I am using karma jasmine and webpack for testing my javascript (es6) based application.

Jquery is successfully loading

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
});
```

All files are compiling successfully.

The problem is I am using jquery library for internalization I18n.
So I use $.i18n('lang')

When I run `karma start karma.conf.js`

Then the error is coming  `$.i18n is not a function`

SO my jquery libraries are not loading even though jquery is loading

can someone help please

Note: All things are working fine in development env. In dev env my entry point is a menifest files that loads all the files include jquery libraries.

In karma.conf my entry point for webpack is all_tests.js which includes all the tests.